# Flash : Impossible to see the actionscript code after a search

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs3

I have a problem with a fla.
I search for a portion of action script code and when i click on the line of the result, i see an empty code window !

Have you ever had a similar problem ?

I use flash cs3 but i don't know the version used to develop this fla.
Is it possible to discover the version used ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 2):

ok, this is not a response really, but i would really recommend you:

1. do not spread your code out over the whole time line, you will have a lot of trouble finding it a yeau later ... IMHO, you shouldn't use the timeline at all except for animation, but not to maintain application states, as many people like to do ... this is VERY unflexible ... do this only for prototyping ... seperate code and visuals, rather than having them all distributed in the .fla, so that you will spend hours searching your code ...
2. keep code outside fla files in .as-files, because

   - this makes maintainance a LOT easier
   - .as files are plain source code, whereas .fla is a proprietary and binary, so it makes you dependant of the usage of CS3
   - you can use good external tools for ActionScript coding (CS3 is DEFINITELY not one)
   - you can use source control etc. with text based files, as action script source files are ...
   - you can cooperate better with flex developers
3. use OOP ... seperate your code into classes and associate those with your symbols ... that way code and graphics are well seperated and the link between graphics and code works through a centralized facility: your library
4. use a decent ActionScript editor, as [FlashDevelop](http://flashdevelop.org) ... it will hugely boost your productivity, with features as code snippets, file templates, find and replace in files etc.

i cannot give you the actual answer, but the thing is, i spent so much time struggeling with the Flash authoring tool, only to learn, that it is awful, and that there are many good tools around that make your life a lot easier ... CS3 is GREAT for drawing/animation/morphing but AWFUL for coding ...

hope this helps anyway ... ;)

greetz

back2dos